# Как избавиться от ���������� в Visual Studio Code

Tags: php

```
<?php
```

// ���������� � ����� ���� ������ �������� ������

```
$war=explode("|",$loc_i[$loc][$login]["war"]);
$war[0]=100; $war[1]=1; $war[2]=24; $war[3]=10; $war[4]=0;  $war[12]="�����"; $war[14]=""; 
$war=implode("|",$war);

$char[6]=time()+10;
$loc_i[$loc][$login]["char"]=implode("|",$char);

additem($loc,$login,"","i.b.fire",1,"items","items",1,0,1);

foreach(array_keys($loc_i[$loc]) as $to) if (substr($to,0,2)!='i.' && $to!=$login) {
    attack($loc,$login,$to,$war,0,1);
    }
```

Comment: у вас либо неправильная кодировка файла, либо не настроена кодировка в студии

Comment: Почти всегда такое видно, когда однобайтовая кодировка с символами код которых больше 128 ( например, кириллица в cp1251) отображается как utf8. Поменяйте в редакторе кодировку на cp1251 и смотрите результат